# How can I remotely start an application on my android phone?

Tags: remote-access

I have an older phone (Android 2.x) that I am not using as a phone.  I am using it in a carboard projector.

I would like to be able to use my desktop computer to instruct it to play a youtube video.  I tried Airdroid, but it doesn't seem to have this functionality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AndroidLost](http://www.androidlost.com/#controls_premium) app, the premium version of which has this facility.

[image]